Getting the relative filepath, filename and test function name automatically, within a forge fuzz test?
Suppose one has:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity >=0.8.26 <0.9.0;

import { PRBTest } from "@prb/test/src/PRBTest.sol";
import { StdCheats } from "forge-std/src/StdCheats.sol";
import { Vm } from "forge-std/src/Vm.sol";

contract Debug is PRBTest, StdCheats {
  uint256 private _someNr;

  /** The setUp() method is called once each fuzz runs is performed.*/
  function setUp() public virtual {
    string memory manuallySpecifiedFilePath="test/some_topic";
    string memory manuallySpecifiedFileName="TestExample";
    string memory manuallySpecifiedTestFunction="testFuzzDebug";
    
    _someNr = 5;
  }

  function testFuzzDebug(uint256 randomValue) public virtual {
    assertEq(_someNr, 5);
    _someNr = 6;
  }
}

Is it possible to get (some of) these manually specified strings automatically, using something like vm.getThisFileName() and vm.getCurrentFunctionName etc.?
Ideally, would it be possible to do so from a function in another file named helper.sol that can be called by different test files for minimum code duplication?
